# Создать диалоговое окно с помощью WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Написать программу, которая при нажатии клавиши ESC выводит окно-диалог о необходимости завершения программы. В окне диалога выводятся два подокна с надписями "Да", "Нет", выбор которых осуществляется нажатием клавиши Tab. При выборе окна "Да" и нажатии клавиши Enter программа завершается, а при выборе окна "Нет" - продолжает работу.

Помогите пожалуйста, я начинающий и не имею понятия как это сделать. В интернете нашел какой-то код но совсем не знаю как его править, поэтому прошу помощи у вас, и не знаю вообще он мне подходит.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

//собственная процедура для обработки
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE
hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
int ret = DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
    NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgProc);
if (ret == 0)
{
    //Если была нажата кнопка Отмена или крестик
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Отмена", "Inform",
        MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
else if (ret == 1)
{
    //Если была нажата кнопка Ок
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Ок", "Inform",
        MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

return ret;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam,
LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    return FALSE;
}
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDOK:
        EndDialog(hwnd, 1);
        return TRUE;
    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
case WM_CLOSE:
{
    EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
    return FALSE;
}
}
return FALSE;//нужно что бы вызвать функцию для прорисовки окда
             //return TRUE;//не будет вызыватся функция протисовки окна
}
```

Пробовал скомпилировать, однако обнаруживаются следующие ошибки:

> Не удаётся открыть файл включение: resource.h: No such file or directory
>
> не удаётся открыть источник файл "resource.h"
>
> идентификатор "IDD_DIALOG1" не определён
>
> аргумент типа "const char*" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"

Comment: А вы не берите любой код из интернета. Почему вы думаете, что любой код из интернета будет правильным?

Comment: @VladD, вроде съедобный код?

Comment: `прорисовки окда` `протисовки окна`=), нужны окна или консольное?

Comment: нужно чтобы открылось окно с двумя кнопками

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, это ж голый код, не написано, откуда ресурсам взяться, и что там должно быть внутри. Ну и с юникодностью там видимые проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Создаешь Win32Project, в окне Resource View выбираешь Accelerator, добавить новую строку Key = VK_ESCAPE, слева его ID выскочит, найди в функции WndProc после case WM_COMMAND: и switch, туда добавить

```
case ID_ACCEL:
if (MessageBox(NULL, TEXT(""), TEXT(""), MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
break;
```

Comment: спасибо, я попробую

Answer (score 0):

Это для winapi ты открыл, тебе это не надо. Но если все таки хочешь углубиться то дам не большую справочную информацию. При создании приложения на winapi создается заголовочный файл (автоматически подключенный) с одноименным названием проекта, и в нем уже подключается сам #include "resource.h".
Далее для того что бы создать окно его надо зарегистрировать в [название_проекта].rc в диалогах и только  после этого у тебя создастся переменная "IDD_DIALOG1". Ну а не соответствие типов и ежу понятно.

Более подробно о данном подходе: http://www.kselax.ru/2013/12/visual-c-sozdanie-dialogovyx-okon/

Comment: мне просто надо сделать эту задачу, не важно как

Comment: я с этого сайта и брал код

Comment: При создании приложения на winapi создается заголовочный файл (автоматически подключенный) с одноименным названием проекта, и в нем уже подключается сам #include "resource.h". Далее для того что бы создать окно его надо зарегистрировать в [название_проекта].rc в диалогах и только после этого у тебя создастся переменная "IDD_DIALOG1". - можете это сделать я не очень понимаю как

Comment: в VS есть отдельный проект типа win32 его создаешь и что там может быть не понятного?

Comment: Только при создании галочку с пустого проекта убери, он тебе все сам забабахает